# How do i make a like button that increase counter on first click and decrease on second click

Tags: javascript, onclick, counter

I'm trying to make a like button that counts and decreases just like the typical social media like button

I came up with this js but it just keeps decreasing when clicked.
and I would really appreciate it if I could get help on how to store the counts on my website

```
        function liked(heart){
            heart.classList.toggle("liked");
            if (heart.liked) {
                click ++;
            } else {
                click --;
            }
            document.getElementById('clicks').innerHTML = click;
        }
```

Comment: `heart.liked` should be `heart.classList.includes("liked")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't give us all your revelant code I'm going to assume some things but you can still use it to help you mimic a `like/dislike` behaviour

In this example I have 2 buttons a like and a dislike button and both of them call the same function.

```
<h1 id="counter">10</h1>
<button id="like" onclick="liked(event)">like</button>
<button id="dislike" onclick="liked(event)">dislike</button>
```

Usually when you click like the common behaviour is `counter +1` but the user can also `unlike` the post or the video, whatever by pressing the button again. Same goes for the `dislike button` which has a `counter-1` behaviour but you can also press it again to return the counter back to what it was before.

You can only have 3 options tho:

- Like it = counter+1
- dislike it = counter-1
- neither of them = counter unchanged

With this code, if like button was pressed and you switch to dislike then the `counter will decrease by 2` since it removes the like state you gave it or it can be the other way around and `go up by 2` if you go from `dislike` to `like`

```
let like_flag = false;
let dislike_flag = false;
function liked(event) {
  let counter = parseFloat(document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML);
  var button = event.target.innerText;
  switch(button){
    case 'like':
        if (like_flag==false && dislike_flag==false) {
        counter++;
        like_flag=true;
      } else if (like_flag==false && dislike_flag==true) {
        counter = counter + 1; //changed this to 1 instead of 2
        like_flag=true;
        dislike_flag=false;
      } else {
        counter--;
        like_flag=false;
      }
    break;
    case 'dislike':
        if (dislike_flag==false && like_flag==false) {
        counter--;
        dislike_flag=true;
      } else if (dislike_flag==false && like_flag==true) {
        counter = counter - 1; //changed this to 1 instead of 2
        dislike_flag=true;
        like_flag=false;
      } else {
        counter++;
        dislike_flag=false;
      }
    break;
  }
  console.log('the button '+button+' was pressed');
  
  document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = counter;
}
```

Since both buttons call same function then we use flags and change them from false to true or from true to false. That way we know what button was pressed and what our code should do next. Hope this helps

https://jsfiddle.net/kenpy/p8oesf61/53/

Comment: Thanks bro, It worked, tho I had to change the counter to increase by 1 instead of 2. I really appreciate

Answer (score 0):

`classList.toggle()` return a boolean value

so, simply do:

```
function liked(heart) 
  {
  if (heart.classList.toggle('liked') )  click++;
  else                                   click--;

  document.getElementById('clicks').textContent = click;
  }
```